# AppendChild to each element of Class

Tags: javascript, html, appendchild

I want to append an element to each div of class "actors" but the function that I wrote adds the element only in the last element with class "actors" (there are two of them in my page). Could you help me how to appendChild correctly in JS please?

````
async function addActor() {
    let actor_name = document.getElementById("actor_name").value;
    let element = document.createElement("p");
    element.innerHTML = `<p>${actor_name}<input id="scriptText" style="width: 40px;" type="text" name="" value="0"></p>`;
    console.log(element);
    let collection = document.getElementsByClassName("actors");


    for(let item of collection){
        await item.appendChild(element);
        console.log(item.innerHTML);
    }
}```
````

Answer (score 6, accepted):

element is passed by reference, so it move in foreach to `div1` then `div2`, and so on `...`

create element in `foreach loop` and it will work

```js
async function addActor() {
    let actor_name = document.getElementById("actor_name").value;
    let collection = document.getElementsByClassName("actors");
    
    for(let item of collection){
      let element = document.createElement("p");
      element.innerHTML = `<p>${actor_name}<input id="scriptText" style="width: 40px;" type="text" name="" value="0"></p>`;
        await item.appendChild(element);
    }
}
```

```html
<input id="actor_name" />
<button onclick="addActor()">Add</button>

<div class="actors">actors 1: </div>
<div class="actors">actors 2: </div>
<div class="actors">actors 3: </div>
<div class="actors">actors 4: </div>
```

Comment: **another note**: the id of new added input in foreach loop is **id="scriptText"**, and that's wrong because id must be unique, so define counter variable in loop and add it to id **id="scriptText_${i}"** & please accept answer if it works, :)